# extract the file.pcd from rviz

Tags: kinect, rviz, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have just link Kinect and rviz node and i ask to you how is possible extract the file.pcd content from the topic (kinect send to rivz). In other word how  can i read the message of the topic? Can i get data file (.pcd) from the image PCL  that I see with Rviz?
Thank you very much.
It's my first experiment with ROS, ad i never use the kinect.
Bye Bye

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31344/extract-the-file.pcd-from-rviz/) by [Roberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2063/roberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/camera/rgb/points

---

Originally posted by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) with karma: 126 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2